# ASP.NET MVC - Split View A/B Testing for Existing Page

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ab-testing

We currently have an existing page for our checkout, let's say `checkout` is the URL.

We would like to create a new version of this page and specifically control the number of users that enter this view/route.
As an example, we would start with `50%` of all users will access the original and the other 50% will access the new.

Ideally, we would like to keep the same URL structure and just change out the view that is displayed. No changes are required for the existing view/path setup.

I have looked at a bunch of A/B Testing options but cannot see one that fits these requirements. Ideally, I'd like to keep this server side. Can anyone recommend any A/B testing options that can help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of accomplishing this. You could use a testing tool server-side SDK like Optimizely or Google Optimize.

Both having cons and pros. This would allow you to make a bucketing decision on the server using a unique user identifier. I typically use a random string in a Cookie. This would allow the controller to switch out the view based on the variant and send goals and objectives to the correct analytics platform. Optimizely's SDK has bucketing built-in and Optimize allows the developer to perform the bucketing themselves. Avoiding the need for an API and therefore slowing the server speed down.

Another way is to add a param to the end of the URL that switches out the view on the server. Then use a redirect test on a front-end testing tool to redirect from the default control to the variation. This typically tends to be better if you are using a caching server as you can avoid the logic involved in cache busting.

Here are a few links to help you out!

https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/experiments
https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/full-stack/docs

Comment: Thanks Thomas both are options I have explored in more detail